# Header/footer doesn't show in page

Tags: twig, drupal-9

I'd like to display my header and my footer inside the batch default **page.html.twig**, but the there's not displayed.

I tried to override the **page--batch.html.twig** file, but still, no result.

This is what I get for the user cancelation account process :

[image]

So I'd like to have all my menus (header + footer) around this progress bar, in order to keep my website design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you were so close to finding the answer :)

You can then use twig_tweak to load your regions into the page, with your theme on page--batch.html.twig (header + footer):
https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet

```
{{ drupal_region('header', 'your_theme') }}
{{ drupal_region('footer', 'your_theme') }}
```